# How can I completely disable Low Memory Killer on Android 11?

Tags: android-11

I am currently using a Pixel 4a 5G, and despite it being an overpowered phone, I am never able to run an app, attend to the whims of life, and resume from where I left off, without Low Memory Killer (LMK) maliciously dropping my private browsing session (and no, the fix is not to stop private browsing, there's a reason I do this, and it's not girlfriend/super-cookie/ISP related).

I have tried everything to get LMK to mind its own business, including rooting, Memory Locker, I have even attempted enabling swap (through Terminal Emulator/other apps, to no avail), etc. Short of just switching to iPhone (any tips here? Does IOS have an annoying LMK, or is it balanced?) I would greatly appreciate any tips that will lead me to disabling this bad behaviour, before I end up destroying my overpriced phone.

Comment: Which web browser are you talking about? Why are you sure it is the Android memory management that kills the private browser session?

Comment: Because it has happened with all of the browsers that I have used: Brave, Firefox, Firefox Beta, Chrome, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's too late, however, I did a lot of digging, and I found some article(s) on changing some of the LMK parameters: there is a file called `/sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree` which you can apparently tweak to fit your needs. You can set them like so: `echo x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6 > /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree`, where x is the threshold you want, divided by the page size (4). More details at https://www.droidviews.com/tweak-android-low-memory-killer-needs/

Comment: @DevFunnie That seems like it would be a good self-answer. (Just one that doesn't work for me personally, I don't have `/sys/module/lowmemorykiller`.)